# Question on definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The following is the definition for continuity at $x_0$

$$\forall \quad\varepsilon > 0\ \quad \exists \delta > 0\ \quad \text{s.t. } \quad |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon $$

But suppose that that $f(x_0)$ is undefined, i.e. there is a "hole" at $f(x_0)$, the definition still holds for continuity since it does not care about what is happening at $f(x_0)$, only around it. Isn't this a problem?

Comment: A function is not continuous at $x_0$ if it is not defined at $x_0.$ It seems like the definition makes that true - $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ is not true if $f(x_0)$ is not defined.

Comment: Continuity at x_0 in the domain. We don't discuss continuity where it is not defined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You mean if its not defined at $f(x_0)$. What if we have an asymptote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is missing something. A function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$ if $\dots$. That $x_0$ is in the domain of the function (i.e. that the function is defined at $x_0$) is part of the definition.

[See for example the Wikipedia article on continuous functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)

Comment: Understood it when I thought of relations, i.e. $x$ has to have a pair $y$.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think
of this definition?

$\forall \ \varepsilon > 0\ 
\ \exists \delta > 0\ 
 \text{s.t. } \ |x_1 - x_0| < \delta
\ \land\ |x_2 - x_0| < \delta
 \implies |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| < \varepsilon
$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. The only thing that matters for continuity are those points at which the function is defined. What occurs outside the domain is irrelevant. If $f(x_0)$ is not defined, then we do not care about it.